# Homebrew App Not Using Python Package

Tags: macos, unix, python, homebrew, duplicity

I installed *duply* using Homebrew and tried to create a backup to Google Drive. Doing so results in the following error:

> BackendException: Google Docs backend requires Google Data APIs Python Client Library

Looking at [*duplicitiy*'s source](https://github.com/turnkeylinux/tklbam-duplicity/blob/master/duplicity/backends/gdocsbackend.py) (*duplicitiy* is what underlies *duply*), I found that this is caused by either `import atom` or `import gdata`, two Python packages. I do however have installed both, and running `import gdata` in Python's REPL works without issues.

I did note that *duplicity* is installed at

```
/usr/local/Cellar/duplicity/0.6.24/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity
```

while the Python packages are at

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gdata
```

So it looks to me as though *duplicity* has somehow got it's own Python distribution? Is this standard procedure? But most importantly: How do I get *duplicity* to find my Python packages?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because somewhat the `atom` package is not in the path. This could be due to several reasons depending on your Python installation method. This quick workaround worked for me... Just add this two lines...

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/')
```

...on top of this duplicity's `gdocsbackend.py` file:

`/usr/local/Cellar/duplicity/0.6.25/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages/duplicity/backends/gdocsbackend.py`

This way you are telling the python file to look for the `atom` module in the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` folder, where it really is.

If you want You can double-check where your atom module is located... Open Python's REPL and type:

```
> import atom
> print atom.__file__
```

You'll get the location that you need to append to your path...

Hope it helps